# Non-Symbolic String to Int or Double in Swift

Tags: swift, char, int, double, type-conversion

Apparently, swift does not have Isnumber() function. I know for integer is string.toInt(). But how about Double? 
I also found someone wrote a toDouble() but it doesn't compile (NSNumber? does not have a member named doubleValue) I am guessing it is because of the optional type is not supported?

```
extension String {
  func toDouble() -> Double? {
    var formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    let number = formatter.numberFromString(self)
    if number == nil {
        return nil
      }
    return number.doubleValue
    }
}
```

source: https://gist.github.com/rhult/5f26d69939214d5f2a3f

Comment: Are you trying to check if a `String` is a number, or if any type of variable is a number?

Answer (score 8):

You're almost there -- `NSNumberFormatter` returns an optional `NSNumber`, which has a `doubleValue` property. You just need to unwrap the `NSNumber` properly:

```
extension String {
    func toDouble() -> Double? {
        enum F {
            static let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
        }
        if let number = F.formatter.numberFromString(self) {
            return number.doubleValue
        }
        return nil
    }
}


"12.345".toDouble()    // 12.345
"12345".toDouble()     // 12345.0
"asdf".toDouble()      // nil
```

Comment: @ericgu Do you mean it won't work for strings like `"$20.00"`? That's probably a whole separate question.

Comment: Yes. I think thats possible but people should be aware of your answers limitations.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `is` operator.

```
if number is Double{
    //do double thinks
}
```

Comment: I think this does not work for a string type but thanks for your input